# How do i fix the error when updating state

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I am making a request to the backend with redux-thunk and fetching the `pricingData`. I keep the items in the `pricingData` first 10 items in the `items` variable by passing certain operations. I want to update the `questionRange` variable with the first `items[0]` value. But using `setQuestionRange` immediately causes infinite loop.
So i tried these:

1. if i have an array with multiple elements, update the `setQuestionRange`. But but the error still persisted
   `React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

```
  if (items.length > 0) {
    setQuestionRange(items[0])
  }
```

2. I used `useEffect`. But this caused another error:

`Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (items) {
      setQuestionRange(items[0])
    }
  }, [items])
```

How can i solve this? Here is my component:

```
import { Container } from '@/components/Container'
import Filters from './Filters'
import Cost from './Filters/Cost'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { getAllPricing } from '@/store/actions/pricingAction'

function SwirlyDoodle({ className }) {
  return (
    <svg
      aria-hidden="true"
      viewBox="0 0 281 40"
      className={className}
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
    >
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M240.172 22.994c-8.007 1.246-15.477 2.23-31.26 4.114-18.506 2.21-26.323 2.977-34.487 3.386-2.971.149-3.727.324-6.566 1.523-15.124 6.388-43.775 9.404-69.425 7.31-26.207-2.14-50.986-7.103-78-15.624C10.912 20.7.988 16.143.734 14.657c-.066-.381.043-.344 1.324.456 10.423 6.506 49.649 16.322 77.8 19.468 23.708 2.65 38.249 2.95 55.821 1.156 9.407-.962 24.451-3.773 25.101-4.692.074-.104.053-.155-.058-.135-1.062.195-13.863-.271-18.848-.687-16.681-1.389-28.722-4.345-38.142-9.364-15.294-8.15-7.298-19.232 14.802-20.514 16.095-.934 32.793 1.517 47.423 6.96 13.524 5.033 17.942 12.326 11.463 18.922l-.859.874.697-.006c2.681-.026 15.304-1.302 29.208-2.953 25.845-3.07 35.659-4.519 54.027-7.978 9.863-1.858 11.021-2.048 13.055-2.145a61.901 61.901 0 0 0 4.506-.417c1.891-.259 2.151-.267 1.543-.047-.402.145-2.33.913-4.285 1.707-4.635 1.882-5.202 2.07-8.736 2.903-3.414.805-19.773 3.797-26.404 4.829Zm40.321-9.93c.1-.066.231-.085.29-.041.059.043-.024.096-.183.119-.177.024-.219-.007-.107-.079ZM172.299 26.22c9.364-6.058 5.161-12.039-12.304-17.51-11.656-3.653-23.145-5.47-35.243-5.576-22.552-.198-33.577 7.462-21.321 14.814 12.012 7.205 32.994 10.557 61.531 9.831 4.563-.116 5.372-.288 7.337-1.559Z"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

export function Pricing() {
  const [fieldSelectionMultipliers, setFieldSelectionMultipliers] = useState(0)
  const [questionRange, setQuestionRange] = useState(0)
  const [audienceCount, setAudienceCount] = useState(100)
  const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState(null)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { pricingData } = useSelector((state) => state.pricing.getPricingData)
  const isPricingDataEmpty = Object.keys(pricingData).length === 0

  const fieldsData =
    !isPricingDataEmpty &&
    pricingData.items.filter((item) => item.content_object.content_type === 27)
  const comboboxData =
    !isPricingDataEmpty &&
    pricingData.items.filter((data) => data.content_object.content_type === 41)

  let items = !comboboxData
    ? []
    : comboboxData.map((item) => ({
        id: item.content_object.nanoid,
        name: item.content_object.name,
        multiplier: item.multiplier,
      }))

  const selectedFields = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(fieldsData))
  const exchangeRate = !isPricingDataEmpty && +pricingData.exchange_rate
  const basePrice = !isPricingDataEmpty && +pricingData.base_price

  const calculateCost = () => {
    let numberFormat = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US')
    let rate = exchangeRate * basePrice
    let questionRangeMultiplier = questionRange ? questionRange.multiplier : 0
    let total_multiplier =
      (+fieldSelectionMultipliers + +questionRangeMultiplier) * rate
    let total = Math.round(total_multiplier * audienceCount * 100) / 100
    setTotalCost(numberFormat.format(total))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateCost()
  }, [fieldSelectionMultipliers, questionRange, exchangeRate, audienceCount])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPricing())
  }, [])

  // if (items) {
  //   setQuestionRange(items[0])
  // }

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (items) {
  //     setQuestionRange(items[0])
  //   }
  // }, [items])

  return (
    <section
      id="pricing"
      aria-label="Pricing"
      className="bg-slate-900 py-20 sm:py-32"
    >
      <Container>
        <div className="bg-slate-900">
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="text-center">
              <h2 className="font-display text-3xl tracking-tight text-white sm:text-4xl">
                <span className="relative whitespace-nowrap">
                  <SwirlyDoodle className="absolute top-1/2 left-0 h-[1em] w-full fill-indigo-400" />
                  <span className="relative">Net fiyatlama,</span>
                </span>{' '}
                sometext
              </h2>
              <p className="my-5 text-lg text-slate-400">
              sometext
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="relative">
            <div className="absolute inset-0 h-1/2 bg-slate-900" />
            <div className="relative mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-lg overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg lg:flex lg:max-w-none">
                <div className="flex-1 bg-white px-6 py-8 lg:p-12">
                  <h3 className="text-2xl font-bold text-gray-900 sm:text-3xl sm:tracking-tight">
                  sometext
                  </h3>
                  <div className="mt-8">
                    <div className="flex items-center">
                      <h4 className="flex-shrink-0 bg-white pr-4 text-base font-semibold text-indigo-600">
                      sometext
                      </h4>
                      <div className="flex-1 border-t-2 border-gray-200" />
                    </div>
                    {selectedFields && (
                      <Filters
                        selectedFields={selectedFields}
                        fieldSelectionMultipliers={fieldSelectionMultipliers}
                        setFieldSelectionMultipliers={
                          setFieldSelectionMultipliers
                        }
                      />
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
                {comboboxData && (
                  <Cost
                    items={items}
                    questionRange={questionRange}
                    setQuestionRange={setQuestionRange}
                    audienceCount={audienceCount}
                    setAudienceCount={setAudienceCount}
                    totalCost={totalCost}
                  />
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: `items` is being created each render, and since it's an array it will trigger the effect (React will compare by reference, not do a deep comparison) causing another render, effect, render, effect etc etc. One option is to use `useMemo` ([documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)) on your `items` assignment.

Comment: I used useMemo but still throws the same error